# How do I display content to users who are not logged in instead of 404 on Private custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, private

I want to display a message like "You must be logged in to view this", with Private custom posts. Theoretically, I want to use something like this:

`if (is_user_logged_in()) {

   // Page code goes here

   }

  else {

    echo "You must be logged in to view this page.";

  }`

This code is in the single-custom.php page template.
The `true` case works just fine. However, if the user is not logged in, instead of seeing "You must be logged in..." I get a 404 instead? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this inside The Loop? I'd try something like this myself:

```
if ($post->post_status == "private" && !is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo "You must be logged in to view this page.";
} else if( $post->post_status == "private" && is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Page code goes here
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to have any custom value "Private" (`var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID)))`

Comment: Sorry about that. Let's try monitoring `$post->post_status` instead. I've edited my answer.

Comment: `echo $post->post_status;` returns `private`. So `$status = $post->post_status; if ($status == "private" && is_user_logged_in()) { echo "Foo<br /><br />";} else {
    echo "You must be logged in to view this page."; }`  I get `Foo` if I'm logged in and looking at a private custom post, but if I'm not logged in, my single-custom.php isn't loaded but 404.php is instead... (soz, dunno why the backticks aren't working for the code -- its basically as per yours but I changed `!== "private"` to `== "private"`

Comment: Hmm, so it sounds like we can detect if it's private once the content is displayed but by then a 404 is served when not logged in. Seems like the determination of wether the page exists or not might be happening at the rewrite level. If you work with plugins, a technique might be to hook onto the rewrite and do something for private posts that allows them to pass the next hurdle.

Comment: It looks like you're in luck. Check out the code posted as an answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9099/wp-plugin-for-terms-of-use I bet you can adapt that for your purposes.